# css style not working in with jstl tag

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have this html code:

```
<div class="login-card">
<h1>Log-in</h1><br>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>* EMAIL ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email_Id" maxlength="100" /></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>* Password</td>
                <!-- <td> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Set your Password"></td> -->
                <td> <input type="password" name="pass" ></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>  <input type="button" name="create" class="login login-submit" value="login" onclick="showDiv()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>          
    </form>
</div>
```

It has css to style the form:

```
.login-card table {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
tr {
    text-align: center;
}
.login-card h1 {
    font-weight: 170;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
}
.login-card input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.login-card input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    /* border-radius: 2px; */
    padding: 0 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The above html code with the css is working fine, but I have to use the below html code:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <div class="login-card">
        <form:form method="post" action="addContact.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:label path="email">Email</form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="email" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:label path="password">password</form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="password" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
```

Now, when I run this  the css is not working

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of that code?

Comment: You can see the ques..i have updated the question

Comment: Sorry, I meant the HTML code that is generated by that JSP code. It must be different from the first chunk of HTML you posted, otherwise you wouldn't get different results.

Comment: Means??how it will be ??can u give any example?

Comment: I mean, the code you posted is JSP code. I'd like to see what the HTML code that is generated by it (the code in your browser) looks like. CHoose 'View source' in the browser.

Comment: The same as above code in jsp..i am getting the same

Comment: Including `<%@taglib ` and all? On the client? That would mean that your server is not configured correctly. The jsp should execute on the server to generate HTML. The jsp code itself should never reach the client.

Answer (score 0):

@Salini You can use the following code in your html with fixed labels and input fields but you have to keep in mind that the `action="` will not work based on html because you need a server side language like Php to process the form.

```
<div class="login-card">
   <form method="post" action="addContact.php">

    <table>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="textfield">email</label></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="password">password</form:label></td>
        <td> <input type="password" name="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    

</form>
```